# Will this be considered as an example for custom Exception?

Tags: java, custom-exceptions

Can the following code be considered as an example for custom exception?
If not, can you please explain why from your point of view?

```
public class UseJDBC
{ 
    public useJDBC() throws Exception
    {
        throw new Exception("ABC");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try 
        {
            useJDBC a = new useJDBC();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this shows usage of a custom exception?

Comment: because i'm creating a child class of exception without naming it!

Comment: There's no child class defined anywhere in that piece of code. To define a child class you should use the `extends` keyword.

Comment: ohkie..i got your point. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. If you want to create a custom exception you have to extend java.lang.Exception or one of its subclasses. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/creating.html